# Não consigo aumentar a largura do meu input

Tags: javascript, css3, react, input

Não consigo aumentar a largura desse input. Uso bootstrap e css. No meu código, não tem essa tag input...

```
                <div className="form-group col-sm-12 col-lg-8">                  
                  {employees.length > 0 && (
                     <AutoCompleteEmployee
                      listEmployee={employees}
                      onChange={this.handleChangeSearch}
                    /> 
                    )}              
               </div>
    </div>
```

Não há nada no momento no meu css sobre isso...

Comment: Verônica, se você está usando React, é provável que a tag `<input>` esteja dentro do componente `AutoCompleteEmployee`.

Comment: como faço para estilizar esse componente ? ...

Comment: Basta abrir o arquivo dele e modificar... Não há nenhum `import AutoCompleteEmployee` no seu arquivo que indique onde está o componente?

Comment: ```return (
      <Fragment>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={onChange}
          onKeyDown={onKeyDown}
          value={userInput}
        />
        {suggestionsListComponent}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }```

Tenho isso, eu coloco o estilo e não funciona

Comment: Aí você precisa usar o atributo `style`, ou usar classes para estilizar com seu CSS ou do Bootstrap.. Você poderia adicionar `class="form-control"` por exemplo, mas aí é com você. Depende de como você quer fazer..

Comment: Consegui! estava fazendo o style errado... obrigada

Comment: @VerônicaEmschermann coloque a resposta aqui e marque como resolvida por favor